# Integrate $\frac{x_i}{|x|^\alpha+2}$ over the unit ball

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I got some problem with the following problem:
Consider an open unit ball $B_1(0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then set:

$u(x)=|x|^{\alpha}$, for $x\in B_1(0)\backslash\{0\}$ and anything else for $x=0$. How to show that

1. $u\in L_{loc}^1(U)\iff \alpha<n$
2. $\frac{x_i}{|x|^{\alpha+2}}\in L_{loc}^1\iff \alpha<n-1$

I managed to calculate the weak derivative $D_iu=-\frac{\alpha x_i}{|x|^{\alpha+2}}$, however, I had no idea how to do the integral over this unit ball to get the relationship between $\alpha$ and $n$, can anyone help? This question confuses me a lot when I learn Sobolev space.

Comment: The idea behind these statements is to use spherical coordinates. Then $|x|^{-\alpha}$ just becomes $r^{-\alpha}$, and since there is no dependence on the angles , one gets $$\int\limits_{B_1(0)} |x|^{-\alpha} dx = \int\limits_0^1 r^{-\alpha}\int\limits_{\partial B_r(0)}dSdr = \int\limits_0^1 r^{-\alpha}\lambda^n(\partial B_r(0))dr.$$
The volume of the sphere with radius $r>0$ is $\lambda^n (\partial B_r(0)) = \gamma_n r^{n-1}$ for some constant $\gamma_n\in\mathbb{R}$, so the integral becomes
$$\gamma_n\int\limits_0^1 r^{n-1-\alpha},$$
which exists if and only if $\alpha <n$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice suggestions. By the way, can I ask what is the meaning of $\lambda$, I have never seen this formula before. And my understanding of the final equivalence relationship is that, we need $n-1-\alpha>-1$ so that we can avoid a divergence result, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct: $\int\limits_0^1 r^{\beta}d r$ exists, if and only if $\beta > -1$. And with $\lambda^n$, I just meant the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, i.e. the $n$-dimensional volume of a Borel-measurable set. Alternatively, one could write this as $|\partial B_r(0)|$ or $vol(B_r(0))$ or several other notations.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I got it.

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of the boundary of a ball $\partial B_r(0)$ is zero. You mean the surface measure $\sigma_{n-1}(\partial B_r(0))=A_{n-1}r^{n-1}\left(=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}r^{n-1}\right)$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo yeah youre right, I misstyped. Cant edit my comment though :(